# Small Gap between my website content and other annoyances relating to gaps

Tags: css, navigation, html

I have a small gap between everything in my webpage and the browser's edge. I must have added some code that has done this, but am unsure what did. What do I do to remove this? Also in my navigation bar, the last link on the right hand side, has a small gap that is not highlighted on hover on the very edge on the right side of it.

I also need help with the gap between the navigation bar + header and the side banners. How do I remove that gap?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Play - Learn - Grow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <span class="headers_t">

            <span class="banner_h">
                <img src="Images\Top_Banner_4.png" alt="Banner" height="150" width ="1240" />
            </span>

            <nav>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="membership.html">Become a Member</a></li>
                    <li><a href="borrow.html">Borrow Toys</a></li>
                    <li><a href="policies.html">Our Policies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </span>

        <span class="banner_l">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <span class="banner_r">
            <img src="Images\Side_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <h2 class="headers">Welcome to the Home Page!</h2>

        <div class="container">

            Our aim is to provide the children of the community with an ever-changing variety of educational and fun toys to enhance
            their cognitive, social, emotional and physical development in the important first six years of their lives.

            <br><br><span class="Links">Be sure to check out our Wikispace site with more information <a href="http://mysocialmediatools-pn.wikispaces.com/">here</a>!</span>

        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy 2013
        </div>


      </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Entire Document CSS */
html{
    height: 100%;
}
/* Header CSS */
.headers_t{
    /* Add something here */
}
.headers{
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Body CSS */
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    height: 50%;
}
/* Navigation CSS */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 14.28%;
    float: left;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Banner / Picture CSS / Text in Images */
.banner_l{
    float: left;
}
.banner_r{
    float: right;
}
.banner_h, img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
/* Link CSS */
a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #028482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active{
    background-color: #FCDC3B;
    color: #AA00FF;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
.Links A:hover{
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

Disregard the .headers_t id in the css, which I am editing right now...unless that's the cause.

The JSFiddle link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U2mVM/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` to your body CSS

so:

```
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: No problem :) it's an easy thing to overlook.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to remove the gap between the navigation bar + top banner and the side banners?

Comment: Hard to tell without an example. use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post your HTML and CSS and I could take a look

Comment: If you could vote my answer as "best" when you can that would be great! :)

Comment: The JSFiddle is at the bottom of the question now.

Comment: It seems to be ok on mine. The best thing to do is vote my answer as "best answer" for my first response and then start a new question with your new problem, otherwise other people on here won't see it and be able to help.